# wagtail localize translate page programmatically with deepl

Tags: wagtail, deepl, wagtail-localize

I'm trying to automate the translation of a Wagtail website with hundreds of pages. My goal is to create a Django command to translate all the pages with deepl. I can't find any documentation about it. Anyone as ever encountered the same issue ?

I'm using Wagtail 5.2 and wagtail-localize 1.7

Answer (score -1):

The documentation for how to use it is [here](https://wagtail-localize.org/latest/tutorial/2-configure-wagtail-localize/) and describes what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't see where it is described. I believe I read all the documentation and I didn't see any reference to what I'm tying to achieve.